# Como editar um campo booleano em uma lista no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Galera, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia **Cursos**, e estou com o seguinte problema. Na minha tela do **Administrador** eu preciso dos campos **Nome do Curso**, **Nome do Aluno** e o campo **Aprovado** que é um campo `booleano`. Essa tela é onde o **Administrador** diz qual **aluno** está **aprovado** no curso em que se inscreveu. Só que na minha `View` só aparece os campos **Nome do Curso** e o campo **Aprovado** e **não** aparece o **Nome do Aluno**, conforme imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O outro problema é que esse meu campo **Aprovado** quando eu marco o `checkbox` ele não tá salvando como `true` no **Banco de Dados**, está sempre ficando `false`.

**Action Aprovacao** do `controller` **Curso**

```
public ActionResult Aprovacao()
    {
        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
    }
```

**Minha View** `Aprovacao`

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Aprovação</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Aluno
        </th>
        <th>
            Aprovado?
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlunoCursos)
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aprovado)*@
                <input type="checkbox" id="Aprovado" name="Aprovado" value="Aprovado"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que pude entender, não há algo que dispare uma *Action* para o *Controller*, então sua *View* precisa de algumas modificações:

## 1. Identificar a `CheckBox` corretamente

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlunoCursos)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBox("Aprovado_" + item.Nome_Curso, new { @class = "Aprovado", id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

## 2. Adicionar Script que dispare a *Action*

Isto pode ser feito por Ajax:

```
$(".Aprovado").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Aprovacao", "Curso")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { id = $(this).attr('id') },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Aprovação feita com sucesso!");
        }
   });
});
```

## 3. Crie uma *Action* `Aprovar` em `AlunoCursosController`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Aprovar(int id)
{
    var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.AlunoCursoId == id);
    alunoCurso.Aprovado = !alunoCurso.Aprovado;
    db.Entry(alunoCurso).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

## Sobre a coluna `Aluno`

Na hora de selecionar `AlunoCursos`, tente o seguinte:

```
public ActionResult Aprovacao()
{
    return View(db.AlunoCursos.Include(ac => ac.Aluno).ToList());
}
```

Para exibir:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlunoCursos.Aluno.Nome)
```

Comment: Ei @Cigano esse código aqui `var alunoCursos = contexto.AlunoCursos.Include(ac => ac.Aluno).ToList();` vai no meu `controller` né?

Comment: @Novato Isso. Só enviar pra *View* `alunoCursos`.

Comment: Meu campo **Aprovado** ainda não está salvando @Cigano, quando eu atualizo a página o `checkbox` volta vazio, e no banco também não está salvando como `true`.

Comment: @Novato Já colocou um breakpoint na *Action* que o Ajax chama?

Comment: Não, vou fazer isso agora @Cigano

Comment: Acho que o problema é aqui `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Aprovar(int id)
        {
            var alunoCursos = db.AlunoCursos.Include(ac => ac.Aluno).ToList();

            return View(alunoCursos);
        }`. Pode me dar uma luz nessa parte aqui **// Selecione aqui o AlunoCurso e mude o Aprovado.**. Não fiz...

Comment: A seleção de `alunoCursos` não vai em `Aprovar`. Veja minha edição. Dentro de `Aprovar` vai a seleção de apenas um `alunoCurso` e lá você edita o booleano.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25093/discussion-between-novato-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Comment: Me dá só um exemplo @Cigano de como eu faria essa seleção de uma `alunoCurso` dentro do `Aprovar` e editar meu campo `booleano`, porque aqui não consegui.

Comment: @Novato Editei a resposta.

Comment: aqui nesse trecho `alunoCurso.Aprovado = !alunoCurso.Aprovado;` deu erro de **NullReferenceException**.

Comment: @Novato Significa que `alunoCurso` é `null`, e que não achou o registro pelo `id` passado. Você está realizando *debug* do código que está escrevendo?

Comment: Sim @Cigano, quando debugo aqui nesse trecho `var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.AlunoCursoId == id);` ele apresenta um `id = 5`